# UWP AppBarButton Visibility doesn't accept Binding Converter at Page.BottomAppBar

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have This xaml:

```
<Page
    x:Class="Tablaturas.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Tablaturas"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:VM="using:Tablaturas.ViewModels"
    xmlns:res="Tablaturas.Resources.Languaje.resw"
    xmlns:cvt="using:Tablaturas.Code"
    mc:Ignorable="d" Loaded="Page_Loaded">
    <Page.BottomAppBar>
        <CommandBar>
            <AppBarButton Style="{StaticResource HamMenuBtnPhone}" Content="" Command="{Binding  ElementName=MainPageGrid,Path=DataContext.SongsViewModel.AddSongCommand}" Visibility="{Binding SongsListMenu,Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}"></AppBarButton>
        </CommandBar>
    </Page.BottomAppBar>
    <Page.Resources>
        <VM:SongsListVM x:Key="ViewModel"/>
        <cvt:boolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis"/>
        <cvt:ObjetToVisibilityConverter x:Key="ObjToVis"/>
        <cvt:NotBoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="NotBoolToVis"/>
    </Page.Resources>
    <Grid        
        x:Name="MainPageGrid"
        DataContext="{StaticResource ViewModel}"
        Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
   </Grid>
</Page>
```

And This error

An exception of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in Tablaturas.exe but was not handled in user code. WinRT information: **Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key BoolToVis** [Line: 14 Position: 177]. Additional information: The text associated with this error code could not be found.

Why if the resource is defined as a resource of the page can't be instantiated at AppBar
Where must declare the resource  ? or 
How can I do to reference it?